# Can I store secure information on an ERC20 coin?

Tags: erc-20, tokens

Is it possible to store secure data on an ERC20 coin that is only accessible by the owner of that coin? An example might be a coin that contains login credentials to a service.

Comment: You can store information in erc20 token contract that is accessible by only owner. You need to create and ownerOnly modifier for the getter and setter of the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you wouldn't be able to directly store info on an ERC20 coin, because this information would be publicly available on the blockchain. However, you could make some type of application, where a person signs a message (or otherwise proves that he owns a wallet with your tokens in it) and then receives credentials to some application.